# Material-UI Override .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to override the CSS property `position` on the `.MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer`. When looking at the https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/#css you can see there is a rule for `root` but there isn't a rule for `.MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer`. I have read the documentation on overriding the CSS properties but I can't seem to get it to work for that class.

Normally I would leverage the rule and do the following

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paper: {
    background: '#010310',
  }
});
```

Then return something like this

```js
const classes = useStyles();

return (
  <DataGrid classes={{ paper: classes.paper }} />
);
```

However, when I replace the word `paper` in the `makeStyles` and in the `return` to be `columnsContainer` it doesn't work.

**Possible Reasons It's Not Working**

Based on the documentation on the CSS for datagrid (link above), the only `Rule` is `root` and since the `.MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer` doesn't have a `Rule` then I need to do it differently. Unfortunately, I haven't found another way that has worked.

I appreciate any help I get, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can give inline style to the class that you want to override and give it an !important flag.

For example if the class you want to override is  .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer then you can simply do this .

```
 .MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer{
         position:  relative !important; // to override the default css property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a local overriding of `MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer`, as you can see on [api doc](https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/), you have to pass your css to `root` class. So:

```
<DataGrid classes={{ root: classes.root }} />
```

Now if you want to override `MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer` in particular, in your `makeStyles` write something like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "&.MuiDataGrid-columnsContainer":{
        background: '#010310',
    }
  }
});
```

Thats it.

Comment: This does not work for me. Could you link a working sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
root: {
            "& .MuiDataGrid-root": {
                color: `#fff`
            },
            "& .MuiIconButton-label": {
                color: `#fff`
            }
        },
```

I put this  `"& .MuiDataGrid-root"` in my main layout and it works very well.

```
   const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        "& .MuiDataGrid-root": {
            color: `#fff`
        },
        "& .MuiIconButton-label": {
            color: `#fff`
        }
    },
    appBar: {
        backgroundColor:'#181745',
        color:theme.palette.primary.main,
        zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
    },
}))
```